# Codeigniter 3: delete all rows older than 2 months

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, codeigniter-3

I'm using codeigniter 3. I want to delete all the rows from table "anwser" that are older than 2 months (datetime in mysql tabel). I don't get an error. But no rows are deleted. 
Any suggestions?

model:

```
    function delete_old_anwsers()
{
    $this->load->model('quiz_model');
    $this->db->where('datum <', 'strtotime('-2 month')');
    $this->db->delete('anwser');
}
```

controller:

```
$this->quiz_model->delete_old_anwsers();
```

Thank you

Solution:

```
    function delete_old_answer()
{
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM answer WHERE datum < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH ");
}
```

Comment: You can try with `$this->db->query("DELETE FROM answer WHERE datum < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)");`.

Comment: @Tpojka  Thank you!

Comment: '    function delete_old_answer()
    {
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM answer WHERE datum < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH ");
    }'

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a crone job which will be executed daily.

In that, you can add this query and it will delete all answers which are old than 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

In Active Record it will be:

```
$this->db->where('datum < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)');
$this->db->delete('anwser');
```